# Magento 2 : Cannot Use REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I tried to use Magento rest api using oauth signature or token-based, but it's a nightmare.

I followed this guide:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html

This other one:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

But, I can retrieve is this message

```
{
  message: "Client is not authorized to access resources",
  parameters: "Magento_Catalog::products" 
}
```

Even if I have admin access.

I tried to activate an integration with callback and identity link but it always says: "Failed to send the necessary data due to an unexpected error"

I' m using a node.js app and I'm trying to retrieve products, but nothing seems to work, I actually don't have an identity link, what does it mean " application login's page " ? I don't have an application login page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, as you said is a nightmare. But I found a great application who helped me to fix this problem. The name is [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/). 
With this app I just create this lines of code that I hope will help you.

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://www.yourlink.com/index.php/rest/V1/modules',
  headers: 
   { 'Postman-Token': 'YOUR TOKEN',
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible)',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```